# Transform log posteriors to the original posteriors

Tags: model-selection, posterior

Using a two stage RJMCMC process I obtain a vector of log posteriors pertaining to each model.  My goal is to convert these to probabilities after normalization (to use in the second stage of the RJMCMC process).

The problem is the log posteriors are large (ex. 1100).  To convert to probabilities (not on the log scale) I would like to do:

```
exp(log.post)/sum(exp(log.post))
```

However this is not possible due to the large values of the log posterior.  Any suggestions on how I can convert?

I would like the probabilities on the original scale, not on the log scale.

Comment: Are these actually *negative* log posteriors?

Comment: No they are positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the expression:

$$\frac{exp(A)}{exp(A)+exp(B)}$$

The generic strategy to compute the above expression when $exp(A)$ overflows would be to transform as follows:

$$\frac{1}{1+exp(B-A)}$$

For example R chokes on:

$$\frac{exp(1100)}{exp(1100)+exp(1104)}$$

But, happily computes the following transformation to yield a value of 0.01798621:

$$\frac{1}{1+exp(1104-1100)}$$

You may still encounter issues of overflow or underflow when you compute $exp(B-A)$ but that should no loner pose a problem as the transformed expression will still be well defined.

Comment: +1, how does this generalize to where there are more than two values: exp(A_1)/(exp(A_1)+...+exp(A_n))?

Comment: @Glen Simply multiply numerator/denominator by exp(-A_1). That should work.

Answer (score 5):

In the general case, use
$$
\dfrac{ \exp\{A_i-\max_j(A_j)\} }{ \sum_k \exp\{A_k-\max_j(A_j)\} }
$$
to avoid overflows. I always use this approach when computing Bayes factors and probabilities.